# Setting Default Screen Options

Tags: pages, options

Is there a way to set default screen options for a page? Ideally what I want is to be able to set screen options so that say for example, my page attributes, Discussion, and custom fields are visible, while everything else is hidden for me and the user. What is currently happening is when I set those options on the page, they default when I leave and reload the page. I want to set it up to that these options remain active, and are the default settings when creating a new page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's what should normally happen.  Can you replicate that on a clean install with no plugins and a default theme?